# Accidentally deleted my user's home folder

Tags: 18.04, user-profile

so, I'm running a home server using Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS and I'm currently controlling it via ssh outside home. I wanted to delete everything I had on my user's home folder so I used "sudo rm -r /home/user" and deleted everything including the user folder. now everytime I do "cd" it says "-bash: cd: /home/user: No such file or directory"
I've already tried to restart the server (via ssh) but still the same.
What should I do to recover my user's home folder?

Comment: There is no 'recovery' in the sense of recovering the previous user directory and any files within it. Those are gone, gone gone. You can use `sudo mkdir` to create a new directory with the correct username, then `sudo chown` to change ownership of the new home directory to the correct user.

Comment: What backup strategy did you put in place?   Knowing that is how you restore your removed files, and we cannot know what you chose to use.

Answer (score 7):

Just recreate the folder, add the default config files, and change the owner to you:

```
sudo mkdir /home/user
cp -a /etc/skel/* /home/user
chown -R user:user /home/user
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried
mkhomedir_helper
Usage: mkhomedir_helper  [ []] ?

If you are asking about recovery of the folder it was possible only before the restart.